# How to run Magento shell script in browser

Tags: php, magento

This question has been asked a few times but none of them solves my issue.
I simply created a file:

> /shell/test.php

```php
<?php
require_once 'abstract.php';
class Mage_Shell_Test extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run() {
        echo 'in-shell-test!';
    }
}
$shell = new Mage_Shell_Test();
$shell->run();
```

and commented out `$this->_validate();` in

> /shell/abstract.php

Then I still see the page of **WHOOPS, OUR BAD...**

Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: I don't have access to the server command line so I can only test the script in browser.

Comment: Please check test.php file have proper permission.

Comment: They all have 644

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `_validate` method which is inherited from `Mage_Shell_Abstract`. This method checks where you are running your script from and it looks like this:

```
protected function _validate()
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        die('This script cannot be run from Browser. This is the shell script.');
    }
}
```

You can change this to return `true`, but this validation was obviously put there for a reason. If you plan on leaving the script there for a longer period, I would recommend looking for a different approach.

Comment: I did mention that I've **already commented it out** to temporarily disable the validation.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. In that case your script should run from the browser as well. Make sure you are not rewriting the method in your own class and that you cleared all file caches (like APC).

Comment: I did cleared the cache but it still doesn't work though.